# rolling 2 dice randomly (java)

Tags: java, random, dice

Two dice will be rolled and 2 random numbers between 1 and 6 will be generated. The sum will
be taken from the 2 numbers and used to decide what is next. If user's sum is 3, 5, 7, 9,11 then they
lose. If the sum is 4, 6, 8, 10 then they win. If sum is 2, 12 then the program automatically rolls the
dice again until the user wins or loses.

1. Create a game for the above algorithm with following constructs in it:
2. Game should ask the user to input his/ her name.
3. Game should be able to generate random numbers between 1 - 6.
4. Program should be able to show 3 alternate paths
   a. Win : when the random number is in 4 , 6, 8, 10
   b. Loose: 3,5,7,9,11
   c. Play again: 2, 12

Basically I need keep getting a new random number if I get sum of 2 or 12 from 2 dice and that has to go into the loop again and again

```
    public class assessmentrollingdicedemo {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter User Name: ");
        String userName = sc.next();

        Random r = new Random();
        int firstRoll = r.nextInt(6);
        int secondRoll = r.nextInt(6);
        firstRoll+= 1;
        secondRoll+= 1;

        int timesWin = 0;
        int timesLose = 0;
        int sumOfdice = firstRoll + secondRoll;

        do
        {   
            System.out.println("Die 1: "+ firstRoll);
            System.out.println("Die 2: "+ secondRoll);
            System.out.println("total: "+ sumOfdice);
                if(sumOfdice == 4 || sumOfdice == 6 || sumOfdice == 8 || sumOfdice == 10)
                {
                    System.out.println("Win");
                    timesWin++;
                }
                if(sumOfdice == 3 || sumOfdice == 5 || sumOfdice == 7 || sumOfdice == 9 || sumOfdice == 11)
                {
                    System.out.println("Lose");
                    timesLose++;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Play Again");
                }


        } while(sumOfdice == 12 || sumOfdice ==2);

        System.out.println("You won " + timesWin + "times");
        System.out.println("You lost " + timesLose + "times");

      }
    }
```

What I expected was rolling again should only applies to when sum of dice is 2 or 12 but I get infinite loops. Please help me if you know the answer.

Comment: You should roll the dice within the loop. Otherwise you always get the same result and therefore an infinite loop.

Comment: Because `firstRoll` never gets updated again and while condition is also wrong `sumOfdice != 12`

Comment: Thank You so much guys that really helped

Comment: Please use the naming conventions. Rename you class into `AssessmentRollingDiceDemo`

Answer (score 0):

sumOfdice  should be assigned a new value in the loop
in the else statement you should re roll the dices

```
...
else{
    System.out.println("Play Again");
    firstRoll = r.nextInt(6);
    secondRoll = r.nextInt(6);
    sumOfdice = firstRoll + secondRoll;
}
...
```

otherwise the while() will loop over the same value.